# Huggingface: Fine-tuning (not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1))

Tags: nlp, huggingface, fine-tuning

I'm trying to fine-tune [erfan226/persian-t5-paraphraser](https://huggingface.co/erfan226/persian-t5-paraphraser) paraphrase generator model for Persian sentences. I used the Persian dataset of [tapaco](https://huggingface.co/datasets/tapaco) and reformatted it to match the [glue (mrpc) dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/glue/viewer/mrpc) which is used in the [fine-tuning documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training). I have uploaded my dataset in [alighasemi/farsi_paraphrase_detection](https://huggingface.co/datasets/alighasemi/farsi_paraphrase_detection).

I followed every step of the Trainer video (Tokenization, ComputerMetrics, TrainingArgs, ...). However, when I run trainer.train() I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3435b262f1ae> in <module>
----> 1 trainer.train()

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/models/t5/modeling_t5.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, inputs_embeds, head_mask, cross_attn_head_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    941             inputs_embeds = self.embed_tokens(input_ids)
    942 
--> 943         batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
    944 
    945         # required mask seq length can be calculated via length of past

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Here's my code:

```
dataset = load_dataset("alighasemi/farsi_paraphrase_detection")
```

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("erfan226/persian-t5-paraphraser")
```

```
def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["sentence1"], examples["sentence2"], truncation=True)
```

```
tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer)
```

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("erfan226/persian-t5-paraphraser", num_labels=2)
```

I could not use the AutoModelForSequenceClassification to load the model since I would get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-5650b38a14f3> in <module>
----> 1 model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("erfan226/persian-t5-paraphraser", num_labels=2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    464                 pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **hub_kwargs, **kwargs
    465             )
--> 466         raise ValueError(
    467             f"Unrecognized configuration class {config.__class__} for this kind of AutoModel: {cls.__name__}.\n"
    468             f"Model type should be one of {', '.join(c.__name__ for c in cls._model_mapping.keys())}."

ValueError: Unrecognized configuration class <class 'transformers.models.t5.configuration_t5.T5Config'> for this kind of AutoModel: AutoModelForSequenceClassification.
Model type should be one of AlbertConfig, BartConfig, BertConfig, BigBirdConfig, BigBirdPegasusConfig, BloomConfig, CamembertConfig, CanineConfig, ConvBertConfig, CTRLConfig, Data2VecTextConfig, DebertaConfig, DebertaV2Config, DistilBertConfig, ElectraConfig, ErnieConfig, EsmConfig, FlaubertConfig, FNetConfig, FunnelConfig, GPT2Config, GPTNeoConfig, GPTJConfig, IBertConfig, LayoutLMConfig, LayoutLMv2Config, LayoutLMv3Config, LEDConfig, LiltConfig, LongformerConfig, LukeConfig, MarkupLMConfig, MBartConfig, MegatronBertConfig, MobileBertConfig, MPNetConfig, MvpConfig, NezhaConfig, NystromformerConfig, OpenAIGPTConfig, OPTConfig, PerceiverConfig, PLBartConfig, QDQBertConfig, ReformerConfig, RemBertConfig, RobertaConfig, RoCBertConfig, RoFormerConfig, SqueezeBertConfig, TapasConfig, TransfoXLConfig, XLMConfig, XLMRobertaConfig, XLMRobertaXLConfig, XLNetConfig, YosoConfig.
```

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    "farsi_paraphraser",
    num_train_epochs=5,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch"
)
```

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_dataset["validation"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
```

```
trainer.train()
```

I would be happy if you could help me